Busybox containers require keep alive loop/parameter
By starting deployment with busybox as an image:
kubectl create deployment test-deployment --image=busybox --dry-run=client --output=yaml > test-deployment.yaml
kubectl apply -f test-deployment.yaml

POD will end up in error state:
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  34s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/test-deployment-6b4c9bbbc7-mfk5m to worker01
  Normal   Pulled     29s                kubelet            Successfully pulled image "busybox" in 3.907s (3.907s including waiting)
  Normal   Pulled     27s                kubelet            Successfully pulled image "busybox" in 1.148s (1.148s including waiting)
  Normal   Pulling    10s (x3 over 33s)  kubelet            Pulling image "busybox"
  Normal   Created    9s (x3 over 29s)   kubelet            Created container busybox
  Normal   Started    9s (x3 over 29s)   kubelet            Started container busybox
  Normal   Pulled     9s                 kubelet            Successfully pulled image "busybox" in 1.294s (1.294s including waiting)
  Warning  BackOff    8s (x3 over 26s)   kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container busybox in pod test-deployment-6b4c9bbbc7-mfk5m_default(7cb42324-eb2a-421d-907c-d20fc412cd4a)

If I replace busybox image with eg. nginx - no problems:
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From               Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled  71s   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/test-deployment-5746d5bc6f-svskj to worker01
  Normal  Pulling    70s   kubelet            Pulling image "nginx"
  Normal  Pulled     50s   kubelet            Successfully pulled image "nginx" in 19.483s (19.483s including waiting)
  Normal  Created    50s   kubelet            Created container nginx
  Normal  Started    49s   kubelet            Started container nginx

Workaround:
To overcome this problem it is required to add extra command to the deployment:
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: busybox
        command: ['sh', '-c', 'while true; do date; sleep 3; done']   <--- HERE
        name: busybox

Question:
Why containers created with busybox require that endless loop to keep it alive WHEREAS eg. nginx does not require any extra commands/parameters?
Could it be because by default nginx image is running nginx/HTTP service and this is replacement for endless loop/container keep alive?

A busybox image starts a shell by default. Since stdin is disconnected, the shell exits immediately (this is exactly the same behavior you see if you try docker run busybox). Pods (containers in general, really) are generally meant to run some sort of persistent service (like a web server, database, etc).

Hi @larsks
How can I make your reply as a solution? There is no such option/button here.
